# don't recognize a facebook user already logged in

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

on my viewDidLoad I have this

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil || FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("principal1", sender: self)

        println("parse user or facebook is loged in...")
    } else {

        // Show the signup or login screen
    }
```

it works fine when I login with parse but not when I login with facebook

my code for a login custom button is (and is outside of any override Function ):

```
@IBAction func fbBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }

        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                println(result)
            }
        })
    }
 performSegueWithIdentifier("principal1", sender: self)

}
```

it seams that is not saving the accesstoken for facebook so the segue on the top is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your appdelegate :

```
import UIKit

import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {    
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

In your view controller :

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    println(result) // Do your stuff here
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Add properties in your plist.info file.

[image]

Add URL Types, FacebookAppID, and FacebookDisplayName Properties

For more you can go through the steps of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: @RobertoCDlGarza Welcome :)